# Can Pygame images go beyond their Rects?

Tags: image, pygame, collision, rect

I'm making a game in Pygame, and I have it so that if the character collides with a rect that it will push the character back a layer of pixels, creating a very small impassable boundary between it and the object. I was wondering that when I started to add art to it if I could have it covered up so it looked like a solid collision, or is there any way how a solid collision could function without their being that layer of pixels? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just create a `Rect` that is a little bit bigger than the `Rect` of the `Surface` using [`inflate`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.inflate):

> Returns a new rectangle with the size changed by the given offset. The rectangle remains centered around its current center. Negative values will shrink the rectangle.

```
s = your_surface # the Surface containing your image .
r = s.get_rect() # the rect of the Surface.
c_r = r.inflate(2, 2) # the rect used for collision detection.
```

Comment: I hope I understood your question correctly. If not, please feel free to clarify :-)

Comment: Ok thanks. I just wanted to make sure that it was possible. I won't be implementing this for a while, but it's very helpful to know. Thanks